# Unused ADCS for Server 2008 R2 Standard. What are the risks associated with removing this service?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ad-certificate-services

I have inherited this system and I am looking at decommissioning this server 2008 R2 Domain Controller/ADCS Server.  This role (ADCS) was never actively used by anyone.  I believe, just because it was installed, that the member domain controllers have used it to create certificates.  I have revoked all of the certificates that have expired under the "Issued Certificates" folder of the CA.  There are 4 active certs here, one for each DC under the template "Domain Controller (DomainController)" and one for the CA under "CA Exchange (CAExchange)".

I have the private key backed up and I have the "ADCS Database" backed up to a folder.  I have Full image backups of this server as well.  I am looking to uninstall the ADCS service and dcpromo this server but I don't have a lot of experience and understanding on this to know if it is safe.  I am using [this removal guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3527.how-to-decommission-a-windows-enterprise-certification-authority-and-how-to-remove-all-related-objects.aspx) but just want to ask the community if I have anything to worry about by revoking the DC and CA certs that are listed and following through with the removal of the ADCS Role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to add: just do it. CA seems to be unused, so there is no implications in removing it accordingly to referenced guide.

Comment: So those certificates that the current DCs grabbed on to I don't really have to worry about.  They'll use them until they expire and then just create new ones?

Comment: DCs always grab their certificates, but actually used in two cases: smart card logon (not in use in your environment) and LDAPS (LDAP over SSL) which is unlikely used either.